# How can I call the Salesforce API from .NET Core

Tags: soap, .net-core, wsdl, salesforce

We are presently calling Salesforce using their SOAP API in our app. It is .NET Framework based (written in C#).

We're trying to move it to .NET Core which does not support System.Web. The Salesforce SOAP client is built in VisualStudio using WSDL and that creates code using System.Web.

Salesforce also has a REST API, but unfortunately it using OAuth for authentication and our system is used by many of our customers on servers that there is no one on it to respond to an OAuth login. So we can't use that.

What's our best option here?

Comment: There are oAuth flows supported by Salesforce that do not require user interaction, notably the JWT flow ([tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/connected-app-basics/connected-app-basics-api-integration))

Comment: @identigral This has promise - thank you